Assign unique_ptr of derived class to a base class
Why this code doesn't compile?
#include <memory>
    
struct Base {
};
    
struct Derived: Base {
    int n;
};
    
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base_ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>(5);
}

I looked into unique_ptr sources and it looks like it allows moving unique_ptrs of derived classes https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unique_ptr.h#L368
I need this so I can collect messages of different type if a collection to futher work with them
The compiler outputs:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/unique_ptr.h:1070:30: error: could not convert ‘std::forward<int>((* & __args#0))’ from ‘int’ to ‘arb::exchange_connector::Base’
  1070 |     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }


Did you try changing it to std::unique_ptr<Derived> base_ptr =... before you asked this question?

You can't assign unique_ptr. Eventuall move()

It has nothing to do with the class hirarchy, but with the fact that Derived is an aggregate and you cannot use make_unique for aggregate initialization like that.
Your code will also similarly fail to compile with a std::unique_ptr<Derived>:
std::unique_ptr<Derived> ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>(5);

One solution is to add a constructor to Derived.
Another issue in your code is that in order to properly destruct a Derived through a Base pointer, you must anyway add a virtual destructor to Base.
Both are shown below:
#include <memory>

struct Base {
    // Add a virtual destructor:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    // Add this constructor:
    Derived(int n_) : n(n_) {}

    int n;
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base_ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>(5);
}

Live demo.

Ah, you're right, of course.

And add virtual destructor to Base to avoid UB.

@Jarod42 good point - added.

guys, thanks a lot, i feel so newb in c++. I thouth struct would have default constructor. upd - it actually has, then why it can't be called inside make_unique?

@baltazar I just saw your question in the comment about the default constructor for a struct. I am not sure exactly why (this would be a different question for a language-laweyer which I am not), but since Derived  is an aggregate it is not considered a constructor you can call with arguments for the members (which is what std::make_unique requires). Aggregate initialization is different than "normal" construction in that respect. You can see more about aggregates here.

Another option is to provide an initializer for Base:
std::make_unique<Derived>(Base{}, 5)

And, as mentioned in the other answer, don't forget to add a virtual destructor to Base.
